# Inserting data inside Database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have a generic repository where I have a method to save data into database. Knowing that I'm changing an old system, I have faced with this situation:

When I have to save an Area, for example, I need to insert the Id of the field based on the last value inserted inside by database, but for some reason when I try to persist this, an error telling that I can't insert null values into the id of the table appears.

I tried to do this:

```
areaRepository.Save(new Area{AreaCode = 999, AreaName =  "teste"});
areaRepository.SaveAll();
```

The save method is:

```
public void Save(T obj)
{
    ctx.Set<T>().Add(obj);
}
```

And the save all method is

```
public void SaveAll()
{
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

After executing the SaveAll method the error rises.

{"ORA-01400: is not possible to insert null in (\"CELG\".\"EPW_AREAS\".\"AREA_CODE\")\nORA-06512: at line 4"}

Knowing that I'm trying to force the AREA_CODE value, why entity framework doesn't add it and consider the value as null?

Is there a way to force it ?

Does anyone can help ?

Thanks in advice.

Update:

Entity class:

```
[Table("EPW_AREAS", Schema="CELG")]
public class Area
{
    [Key]
    [Column("AREA_CODE")]
    public int AreCode { get; set; }
    [Column("AREA_NAME")]
    public string AreName { get; set; }
}
```

Update 2

Context

```
    public WsContext(string sConnectionString)
        : base(sConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
```

Update 3

```
CREATE TABLE CELG.EPW_AREAS
(
  AREA_CODE  NUMBER                            NOT NULL,
  AREA_NAME    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
)
TABLESPACE TBS_CELG_DATA
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
        INITIAL          64K
        NEXT             1M
        MINEXTENTS       1
        MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
        PCTINCREASE      0
        BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
       )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
```

Comment: The most likely problem is that your mapping is wrong. If you want further help you will have to provide the mapping code.

Comment: Can you post your context class?

Comment: are you sure that the column accepts null values and it is not a "not null" column?

Comment: Igor, I added the mapping of my entity.

Comment: Isma , here is the context

Comment: Ioannis, the column really can't accept nullable values, knowing that I'm trying to add an Id value at my database. The problem is that even forcing the value, the framework is passing null to the query and I really don't know why .

Comment: Are you using CodeFirst or DatabaseFirst?

Comment: @ruynunes  so according to your model there is no Id column in Area entity ? or AreaCore is primary column for that entity ?

Comment: No. I'm just testing the implementation of the entity framework. Then I mapped it by myself. Is there anyway to use code first or database first at an oracle database ?

Comment: This means you created the Database yourself? Can you add the script of the CreateTable?

Comment: @RJ the annotation key as I know,  is the identification for the id column at an entity or I am wrong ?

Comment: @Nikolaus this is an old system at where I work. this isn't a new table. I just tried to test my CRUD based at this table and I mapped this manually. I'm gonna update my post to include the script

Comment: @ruynunes Key attribute makes the AreCode as a primary key and it is auto-generated. so I think in your scenario the AreCode need not be passed a value while creating the record. I am not sure if you forcefully assign the value for it it will be considered.

Comment: @RJ I tried to force but without any success. Is there a way to do that even using the [Key] annotation? Or should I remove it ? but the problem is if I'm gonna have any other errors by removing it .

Comment: @ruynunes The CreateTable script does not contain a Primary Key. Maybe EF handles the AreaCode as autogenerated and supplies null, while the dbms does expect a Value. Is this possible?

Comment: See Isma's answer...

Comment: @Isma answer is much better than article link i posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error might occur because Entity Framework is ignoring the value you set for  your AreaCode property because it is set up as the Key and by convention EF expects this key to be generated automatically by your DB system.

You can try to disable it as follows:

```
[Table("EPW_AREAS", Schema="CELG")]
public class Area
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column("AREA_CODE")]
    public int AreCode { get; set; }
    [Column("AREA_NAME")]
    public string AreName { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure you don't try to add the same area code more than once though.

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks man !!!!! I'm really a noob into entity framework and those easy things sometimes aren't so easy to discover !

Comment: No problem, we've all been there ;-)